# Role Assignment multiple Azure Functions to the same storage account in an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I've been trying to update an ARM template which creates a stack of resources on Azure.

I am trying to add the functions as Reader and Data Access assignments to the storage account. Adding only one works just fine, although even that took a while to get it working. When I try to add multiple my template won't even validate, because of this error :
`"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/strgegitestv2qaeu/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/3273386b-cde7-5e43-a242-a64d4ed23bee' at line '208' and column '9' is defined multiple times in a template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#resources for usage details.'.","additionalInfo":[{"type":"TemplateViolation","info":{"lineNumber":208,"linePosition":9,"path":"properties.template.resources[1]"}}]}`

Now I believe I understand why that is, I'm basically calling the same roleAssignment multiple times, when what I believe I should do is create a GUID for each function service identity and call those. Problem is I'm not sure how to do that exactly, can't find enough information in the documentation or anywhere online. This is a snippet of my ARM template :

```
"variables": {
"storageAccountName": "[concat('strg', variables('commonId'))]",
"readeranddataaccess": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', 'c12c1c16-33a1-487b-954d-41c89c60f349')]",
"servicekeyoperatorrole": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '81a9662b-bebf-436f-a333-f67b29880f12')]",
"TestVariable": "[concat(variables('storageAccountName'),'/Microsoft.Authorization/',guid(subscription().subscriptionId))]"
}

"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
                "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            },"resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2020-08-01-preview",
            "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_RAGRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
                "minimumTlsVersion": "TLS1_2",
                "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
                "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "keyType": "Account",
                            "enabled": true
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "accessTier": "Hot"
            },
{
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('TestVariable'))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('readeranddataaccess')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functioName1')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('TestVariable'))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('readeranddataaccess')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName2')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('TestVariable'))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('readeranddataaccess')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName3')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat(variables('TestVariable'))]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('readeranddataaccess')]",
                "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName4')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
                "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
            }
        }


If that is indeed the issue how can I create a GUID for each of the SystemManaged Identities of my Functions and call them to the "name" of my RoleAssignments?
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of your roleAssignment needs to be unique in the tenant - based on the principal, role and scope of the assignment.  In your case you can do something like this:

```
guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName1')), resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), variables('readanddataaccess'))
```

Note that the `variables('functionName1')` would match the principal - so functionName1, functionName2, ... as needed for each roleAssignment.

That help?

---

Ok, try this (this is relatively new and meant to simplify that segmenting problem):

```
"variables": {
    "raNameFunctionApp1": "[guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName1')), resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), variables('readanddataaccess'))]"
},
...
{
    "scope": "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
    "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
    "apiVersion": "2020-04-01-preview",
    "name": "[variables('raNameFunctionApp1'))]",
    "properties": {
        "roleDefinitionId": "[variables('readeranddataaccess')]",
        "principalId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('functionName1')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
        "principalType": "ServicePrincipal"
    }
},
```

Comment: I think I'm almost there. Trying to create the role assignments that way now, I keep getting the dreaded.

```'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments' at line '212' and column '79' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name```.

I added each role assgnmt as a variable and passing it as variable to the 'name'. From my understanding since this is a root resource type it should have one more segment length, which it has

Comment: This is the variables I'm passing : 

```
 `"TestVariable3": "[concat(guid(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('mappingSiteName')), resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), variables('readeranddataaccess')))]"`
```


If I'm reading it correctly, it has 3 segment length which is one less than the type which is : 
```"type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/providers/roleAssignments"```

Comment: Sorry for the amount of replies to this, the variables I'm passing are quite long in themselves as well, so I think that's why my 'TestVariable3' has considerably more segments than the Type

Comment: That was it thank you!

For anyone who is interested, the solution above will also allow you to update your provisioned stack with no conflicts which is what happens when passing the GUID as a parameter